# How do I get values from HTML tags using Python 3

Tags: python, html, regex, list

How do you obtain html values between tags without using Beautiful Soup with Python 3? 
I am trying to make a list out of the values between the tags. 
How would I do this? Would I use Regular Expression?

```
<td class="standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name">Chelsea</td>
<td class="standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name">Tottenham</td>
<td class="standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name">Liverpool</td>
```

How would I obtain the values like 'Chelsea', 'Tottenham', 'Liverpool'?

Thanks

Comment: first result from Google, https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: is there any specific reason for not using `Beautiful Soup` ?

Comment: I am told I can only use standard libraries

Comment: Change your school, someone that tells you to parse html without a standard parser is a joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend bs4, but if you want to use regular expressions :

```
my_str = '<td class="standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name">Chelsea</td>'  
match = re.search('>(.*?)</', my_str)  
if match : 
    match = match.group(1)
```

This will match any string between html tags

```
print(match)
Chelsea
```

Keep in mind that `search` will return the first match ( if any , else none )
If you want all occurrences , you should use `findall` instead

Comment: what happens if there's no match ?

Comment: @Pedro Lobito i never claimed that this is the best solution ( in fact i recommended bs4 ) , it's just a fast example.  Also i mentioned that `re.search` may return `None` if that's what you mean .  Anyway , i updated the code to handle that case , thanks for your input .

Comment: Great, you can use `if match:` only.